# Ionic, subheader renders differently in safari and ios

Tags: html, ios, css, safari, ionic-framework

Hey I need your help with some css rendering issue, I have this page running on ios and safari.

This is safari:

[image]

This is device:

[image]

My styles are:

```
.subheader-large {
  position: absolute;
  top: 44px;
  /*height: 44px;*/
  line-height: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  line-height: 44px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 30;
  background-color: white;
}
```

and content is with:

```
.has-subheader {
    top: 88px;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a codepen please?

Comment: codepen doesn't really work well with ionic, I will try to give a working sample

Comment: [Codepen is used by the ionic team](http://codepen.io/ionic/pens/public/?grid_type=list). But if you prefer another tool.. no problem ;)

Comment: well... this is as far as I got it working http://codepen.io/ospfranco/pen/QNOjGV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, after taking a look at the content div running on device I noticed a different rule was being applied, anyways I added the following rule:

```
.platform-ios.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen) .subheader-large {
  top: 64px;
}
```

it works as intented now.